# Setting project with selenium and pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, pytest, fixtures

Recently I have started a new project with Selenium and Pytest and I'm not sure what is the best way to set up the driver and the general structure of the project.

I have set up the driver inside BaseClass:

```
class BaseClass:
    service_obj = Service()
    chrome_options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=chrome_options)
```

Page Object Models as well as test themselves inherit from BaseClass:

```
# Page Object class
class LoginPage(BaseClass):
    username_input = (By.ID, 'username-input')
    username_password = (By.ID, 'username-password')

    @classmethod
    def type_login_password(self, login, password):
        self.driver.find_element(LoginPage.username_input).send_keys(login)
        self.driver.find_element(LoginPage.username_password).send_keys(password)

    
# Test class
class TestLogin(BaseClass):
    def test_login(self):
        LoginPage.type_login_password('username', 'password')
```

The issue I try to resolve is that with the solution above all of my methods inside LoginPage would be @classmethods. Is it the right solution? I don't see why I would have to initialize the driver object each time inside my test class or page object class.

I know that I could simply remove classes, but remaining them helps with better setting up the test environment -> pytest fixtures with different scopes

I tried looking for answers on different forums or blogs but from what I've found within most examples people simply initialize new driver instance inside each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications in your BaseClass. The @pytest.fixture decorator allows you to define reusable fixtures for setup and teardown.

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    service_obj = Service()
    chrome_options = Options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=chrome_options)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

you can remove the classmethod decorator and use the self.driver instance variable that is set up by the setup fixture.

```
class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.username_input = (By.ID, 'username-input')
        self.username_password = (By.ID, 'username-password')

    def type_login_password(self, login, password):
        self.driver.find_element(*self.username_input).send_keys(login)
        self.driver.find_element(*self.username_password).send_keys(password)

class TestLogin:
    def test_login(self):
        page = LoginPage(self.driver)
        page.type_login_password('username', 'password')
```

Hope it will work for you .

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!

With this solution I really don't like the fact that when I type self.driver. I'm not getting suggestions from VSC. Do you know any solution to that?

And what in situation when I'd like to access the driver in another fixture within conftest.py file? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a framework that already combines `selenium` and `pytest` with the page object model: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase

[image]

Here's a script with login and page objects. Runs with `pytest` / `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class LoginPage:
    def login_to_swag_labs(self, sb, username):
        sb.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        sb.type("#user-name", username)
        sb.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        sb.click('input[type="submit"]')

class MyTests(BaseCase):
    def test_swag_labs_login(self):
        LoginPage().login_to_swag_labs(self, "standard_user")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_element('div:contains("Sauce Labs Backpack")')
        self.js_click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("div#login_button_container")
```

(There's no need to use `@classmethod`. Lots of useful command-line options such as `--rs` to reuse the browser session between different tests. You can even change the default browser from Chrome using: `--edge`, `--firefox`, `--safari`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mintz!

Actually, I have considered SeleniumBase, but in the company I'm currently working in there are a few other projects that uses raw selenium, so I'm rather gonna stick with that